# CreateProcess : escape spaces in the application path

Tags: delphi, createprocess

We need to execute ffmpeg in a command window in my delphi application.

We found the solution to protect the path with the function "ExtractShortPathName".

But on some computers we can't get the 8.3 path (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation is 2) and we want to find another way to escape the spaces.

Here is the code :

```
sParameters := '"C:\Users\[...]\input.wav" -r 12.03 -f image2 -i "C:\Users\[...]\delphilm%d.png" -vf "scale=1024:704" -ab 96k -r 24 -b 2000k  -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -fpre "C:\[...]\libx264-normal.ffpreset" "C:\Users\[...]\export.mp4"';
sCommand := 'C:\Program Files\My application\utils\bin\ffmpeg.exe';
Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C '+ProtectPath(sCommand)+' '+sParameters),nil, nil, True, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI);
```

With the ProtectPath function :

```
function ProtectPath(sCommand:Widestring):Widestring;
begin
  Result := sCommand;
  // get the 8.3 path
  Result := ExtractShortPathName(sCommand);
  // if 8.3 path is not accessible
  if(Pos(' ', Result)>0)then begin
    //Result := '"'+sCommand+'"';    --> do not work
    //Result := StrReplace(sCommand, ' ','" "');  --> do not work
    //Result := StrReplace(sCommand, ' ','^ ');  --> do not work
    //Result := StrReplace(sCommand, ' ','\ ');  --> do not work
    //Result := StrReplace(sCommand, ' ','\\ ');   --> do not work
    //Result := StrReplace(sCommand, ' ','/ ');  --> do not work
    //Result := StrReplace(sCommand, ' ','// ');  --> do not work
  end;
end;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Replace backslashes with forward slashes. I usually use it in C++. Only works for paths though. Nothing else. Hopefully it works here.

Comment: OT: It still makes me wonder why do people tend to use `cmd.exe /C`. Isn't just easier to directly execute the application ?

Comment: The forward slashes don't work.

Comment: We use cmd.exe to analyse the output of ffmpeg during the process.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx  The comments section states that it will fail if the file does not have a short name. It seems as though there are quite a few `gotchas` using this function. Some systems do not have short-names for some paths.

Comment: We try to force the short-name on the computer but it does not work.

Comment: There's no obvious need for `cmd.exe`. That's what's giving you the pain. Do without it.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to retrieve the 8.3 filename.  All you have to do is wrap a long path with a single pair of quotation marks if it contains any space characters in it (like you are already doing with some of your FFMPEG parameters).  Then, get rid of `cmd.exe` altogether and just call `ffmpeg.exe` directly instead.

```
sCommand := '"C:\Program Files\My application\utils\bin\ffmpeg.exe"';

sParameters := '"C:\Users\[...]\input.wav" -r 12.03 -f image2 -i "C:\Users\[...]\delphilm%d.png" -vf "scale=1024:704" -ab 96k -r 24 -b 2000k  -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -fpre "C:\[...]\libx264-normal.ffpreset" "C:\Users\[...]\export.mp4"';

Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(sCommand + ' ' + sParameters), nil, nil, True, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI);
```

If you want to do the quoting dynamically, use `(Ansi)QuotedStr()` for that, eg:

```
function ProtectParam(sParam: String): String;
begin
  if LastDelimiter(' "', sParam) <> 0 then
    Result := QuotedStr(sParam)
  else
    Result := sParam;
end;
```

```
FFMPEG := 'C:\Program Files\My application\utils\bin\ffmpeg.exe';
InputFile := 'C:\Users\[...]\input.wav';
PngFile := 'C:\Users\[...]\delphilm%d.png';
PresetFile := 'C:\[...]\libx264-normal.ffpreset';
ExportFile := 'C:\Users\[...]\export.mp4';

sCommand := ProtectParam(FFMPEG) + ' ' + ProtectParam(InputFile) + ' -r 12.03 -f image2 -i ' + ProtectParam(PngFile) + ' -vf "scale=1024:704" -ab 96k -r 24 -b 2000k  -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -fpre ' + ProtectParam(PresetFile) + ' ' + ProtectParam(ExportFile);

Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(sCommand), nil, nil, True, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real reason to use `cmd.exe` here. It's just adding an extra layer of complexity that burns you. You are asking `cmd.exe` to call `CreateProcess` to start `ffmpeg`, so why not do it directly?

That said, a cheap and cheerful way to side-step the problem is to make use of the working directory. Pass `'C:\Program Files\My application\utils\bin'` for the working directory of the new process, and then `PChar('cmd.exe /C ffmpeg.exe '+sParameters)` is all you need.